# How to create specific Domain User in windows server 2012?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I want to create AD User in the domain give specific permission to the user something like ,Grant permission in Active Directory **to add users / modify / changed password / add them to group them but not delete them**.But the same time that AD user must be RDP User.Is it possible then How ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Those are different kind of privileges:

- Assing the permissions needed using the [Delegation of Control Wizard](https://www.howtogeek.com/50166/using-the-delegation-of-control-wizard-to-assign-permissions-in-server-2008/).
- You could add the user to group `Builtin\Remote Desktop Users` to give RDP access.

  > Members in this group are granted the right to logon remotely

In order to manage Active Directory users this user doesn't necessarily need RDP access to the server. It's also possible to install [Remote Server Administration Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) on any workstation.

Comment: I added user to the Remote Desktop Group & not Succeeded.When I edit local GPO & enable the "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services" User can log it through RDP.But the user(non admin) has administrator rights.